# nsolve with a variable in the x-domain

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to find the root of system of equations, 2 variables (mu,sig):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf
from sympy.solvers import nsolve
from sympy import Symbol
import mpmath

bins = [0.09,0.2]
power = [1.3,1.5]


def CDF(x,sig,mu):
    return(0.5+0.5*erf((np.log(x)-mu)/(2*np.pi*sigma)))

def findRoots(power,bins):
    mu = Symbol('x1')
    sig = Symbol('x2')

    f1 = CDF(np.exp(mu) + bins[0],mu,sig) - CDF(0,mu,sig) - power[0]
    f2 = CDF(np.exp(mu) + bins[1],mu,sig) - CDF(np.exp(mu) + bins[2],mu,sig) - power[1]

    print(nsolve((f1,f2),(mu,sig),(0.6,0.1)))
```

This gives the following error message:

```
    f1 = CDF(np.exp(mu) + bins[0],mu,sig) - CDF(0,mu,sig) - power[0]
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

So apperently sympy is not happy about having a variable in the 'x' domain.

Is there a way to circumvent this?

In mathematica this would look something like this:

```
f1=0.1;d1=0.3;
f2=0.2;d2=0.2;
FindRoot[{NIntegrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[mu,sig],x],{x,0,Exp[mu]+exp[f1]}]==d1,NIntegrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[mu,sig],x],{x,Exp[mu]+exp[f1],Exp[mu]+exp[f2]}]==d2},{mu,0.01,5}{sig,0.01,5}]
```

With arbitarly changed variables but same functionality!

Answer (score 0):

got it. need to use sympy functions instead of numpy ones...

e.g.

```
from sympy import exp, erf, log, pi
```

and replace with the respective numpy functions...